# Solution verification on Munkres Topology, Section 33, Exercise 4

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

**Problem** A set $A$ is "$G_\delta$ set" in $X$ if $A$ is the intersection of a countable collection of open sets of $X$. Let $X$ be normal. Show that there exists a continuous function $f: X \longrightarrow [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in A$, and $f(x) > 0$ for $x \notin A$, if and only if $A$ is a closed $G_\delta$ set in $X$.

*Note* A function satisfying the requirements of this theorem is said to **vanish precisely** on $A$.

---

**Solution** ($\implies$) The unit interval is Hausdorff, and $\{0\}$ is closed. It follows that $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed. Also,

$$
f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \bigcap^{\infty}_{n = 1} f^{-1} \left( \left[0, \frac{1}{n} \right) \right),
$$
which is a countable intersection of open sets.

($\impliedby$) Let $A = \bigcap^{\infty}_{n = 1} U_n$. Since $X$ is normal, we can construct a continuous function $f_n$ which satisfies $f_n(A) = \{0\}$ and $f_n({U_n}^c) = \left\{ \frac{1}{2^n} \right\}$ by applying Urysohn's lemma. It is trivial that $f = \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} f_n$ converges pointwise(by monotone convergence theorem) and vanishes precisely on $A$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\epsilon > \frac{1}{2^N}$. Then $\left|f_m(x) - f_n(x)\right| < \epsilon$ for any $m, n > N + 1$. It follows that $f_n$ converges uniformly to some function, namely $f$, which is desired function.

---

How does it look? Does it contain any critical errors?

Comment: Looks pretty good!

Comment: Looks fine to me..............